# Centring a QTextEdit in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit, qmainwindow

**My Experience:**

I am confident using python in general but I am new to PyQt5.

**What I am working on:**

I am currently using PyQt5 for Python 3.6 to build a text editor, it has all of the basic features a normal text editor would have e.g saving files, opening files, changing fonts, etc.

**My issue**

Currently I have built a basic layout for my program containing a menu bar with various buttons, I am now at the point of adding the 'textEdit' box into the program but it does not appear in the centre of the UI:

[image: The textbox]

The text box is also relatively small compared to the size of the overall window, so currently I am left with a small, top-left aligned text box. How can I centre this text box and make it span the whole window.

My main class:

```
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Text Editor'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 1080
        self.height = 920
        self.text = QTextEdit(self)

    self.initUI()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the QTextEdit as the central widget of QMainWindow as shown below:

```
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Text Editor'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 1080
        self.height = 920

        self.text = QTextEdit(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text)
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Or add it inside the central widget through a layout:

```
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Text Editor'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 1080
        self.height = 920

        self.widget = QWidget(self)

        self.text = QTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.text)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]